# Which Events are fired When Request Are made in WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, events

I wanted to know, when WebGet/WebInvoke requests are made in WCF service which built-in events are fired & can I override them? same for sending a response?

In all the events I want to access the Data which is being sent or received.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

best way to do this is:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.idispatchmessageinspector.aspx

WCF will invoke your implementation of the dispatch message inspector, after receive request, and before send reply. There you have access to the raw Message instance, you can even modify it if required.